# Finding a representing matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
B = (u_1,u_2,u_3)
$$
$B$ is a basis of $(Z_7)^3$.

$u_1 = (1,2,3), u_2 = (1,6,0), u_3 = (1,1,1)$

Let $T:(Z_7)^3 \to (Z_7)^3$ a linear transformation such that:

$$
T(u_1) = (1,6,0), T(u_2) = (5,2,0), T(u_3) = (3,1,2)
$$

Find the representing matrix $[T]_B$ of $T$ with respect to the basis $B$.

---

My attempmt: (didnt succeed)

We will find each $T(u)$ as linear combination of the basis vectors:

$$
T(u_1) = (1,6,0) = 0u_1 + 1u_2 + 0u_3
$$
$$
T(u_2) = (5,2,0) = 0u_1 + 5u_2 + 0u_3
$$
$$
T(u_3) = (3,1,2) = 0u_1 + 1u_2 + 2u_3
$$

So i thought that the representing matrix will hence be:
$$
[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0 \\ 1&5&1 \\ 0&0&2\end{bmatrix}
$$

But its clearly doesnt work, e.g. lets try to calculate $T(u_1)$:

$$
T(u_1) = [T]_Bu_1 = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0 \\ 1&5&1 \\ 0&0&2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\6 \end{bmatrix}
$$

But we know that: 
$$
T(u_1) = (1,6,0)
$$

Where is my mistake?

Help.

Comment: I think you meant $B$ is a basis of $(Z_\color{red}7)^3$

Comment: Your matrix is correct but you calculated $T(u_1)$ incorrectly

Comment: I keep getting the same result, can you show me the correct calculation? 
its $(0+0+0, 1+3+3, 0+0+6)^T = (0,0,6)^T$ Where is the calc mistake?

Answer (score 4):

The matrix representation of $T$ is right, but the equation $T(u_1) = [T]_B u_1$ is clearly wrong. It should be instead

> $$[T(u_1)]_B = [T]_B[u_1]_B,$$

where, for a vector $x = a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 + a_3u_3$, $[x]_B$ represents the column vector
$$[x]_B = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Let's see, in this case, we have
$$[u_1]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and then, $[T]_B[u_1]_B$ is just the first column of the matrix, as desired.

Comment: Useful fact that relative to itself the $i$th basis vector is $e_i$.

Comment: So if i understand correct, for every basis i will get that the basis, in respect to itself, be written as if it was the standard basis, for example, here, $[u_1]_B = (1,0,0)^T$, $[u_2]_B = (0,1,0)$, $[u_3]_B = (0,0,1)$?

Comment: That's right! Since $$\begin{align} u_1 &= 1u_1+0u_2+0u_3 \\ u_2 &= 0u_1+1u_2+0u_3 \\ u_3 &= 0u_1+0u_2+1u_3 \end{align}$$ we have that $[u_i]_B = e_i$ for $i=1,2,3$.